# Laravel 5. DB::select working principles

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Here is the raw SQL query:

```
    $best_price = DB::select('select id,product_id, shop_name, product_name, brand, weight_volume, min(price)

    FROM (
            select
    p.id, p.product_id, p.shop_id, s.shop_name, pr.product_name, pr.brand, coalesce(pr.weight, pr.volume) weight_volume, p.price

    from prices p
    inner join (
            select p1.id price_id,p1.product_id id, max(p1.created_at) maxed_date

    from prices p1

    where product_id= ?

    group by p1.id, p1.product_id, p1.shop_id) grouped on grouped.maxed_date=p.created_at and grouped.price_id=p.id
    join products pr on pr.id=p.product_id
    join shop_names s on s.id=p.shop_id

    group by p.id, p.product_id, p.shop_id) grouped

    GROUP BY product_id,shop_name', [$request->product]);
```

In DBeaver I get result of one line with `min(price)` of `"Metro C&C"`.

But if I do `dd($best_price)` I get the following result:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#158 ▼
    +"id": 46
    +"product_id": 69
    +"shop_name": "Metro C&C"
    +"product_name": "Cream"
    +"brand": ""Tastyland""
    +"weight_volume": 0.22
    +"min(price)": 300.0
  }
  1 => {#160 ▼
    +"id": 47
    +"product_id": 69
    +"shop_name": "Klopshop"
    +"product_name": "Cream"
    +"brand": ""Tastyland""
    +"weight_volume": 0.22
    +"min(price)": 300.0
  }
]
```

And if I do

```
foreach($best_price as $best_price_id) {
            return $best_price_id->shop_name;
        };
```

I received the following result `"Metro C&C"`.

I have the following questions:

1. How does Laravel understand, that there are two results with minimum price of 300(actually this is the result that I expect) while DBeaver provides only one? How should I change the SQL query to get result of 2 rows?
2. Why does `foreach` return only the first row?

Comment: "Why does foreach return only the first row?" Because `return` terminates the loop!

Comment: your loop is terminated at return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things, first use Laravel's query builder methods to write a query. Not row sql. You can get them from [this official document.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries)

To return all values, not a single.

```
$the_best_price = []; //initializing an empty array.

foreach($best_price as $best_price_id) {
        $the_best_price[] = $best_price_id->shop_name;
    };
return $the_best_price;  //this will return all as an array,
```

when you use `return` it terminates the execution and return what ever it has, in your question, it only has only one value.First make an array then return it outside the `foreach` loop.